# Double iterated integration: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: definite-integrals

The question is:

integrate $f(x,y) = 1$ on the region bounded by:

$$0 \le y \le -x^2 + 1$$
$$-1 \le x \le 0.5$$

I've turned this into the following integral:

$$\int_0^1 \int^{0.5}_{\sqrt{1-y}} 1 dx dy$$

When I evaluate this, I get $\frac{1}{6}$.  However, this is equivalent to the 1D integral:

$$\int_{-1}^{0.5} (-x^2 + 1)dx$$

which correctly evaluates to 1.125.

Clearly, my bounds are a problem, but I can't figure out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $$\int_0^{0.75} \int^{0.5}_{-\sqrt{1-y}} 1 dx dy $$ + $$\int_{0.75} ^1\int^{\sqrt{1-y}}_{-\sqrt{1-y}} 1 dx dy $$

Indeed, x=0.5 intersects the parabola in y=0.75

Comment: Shouldn't the upper bound on the internal integral be 0.5? (I suspect yes, since with that bound we get the correct answer :-) ).  I see what I did wrong, though.  I was integrating on the wrong part of the parabola.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky Yes, you're right. I've edited my answer so now it's correct ;)

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is.  If we use those bounds, we end up with the value 1.333.  On the other hand, if we do the 1D integration, we get 1.125.  I believe the challenge here is that we need to consider several sub-domains, since the bounds are not monotonic and thus don't have inverses

Comment: @MichaelStachowsky this last should be great :-)

Comment: Yes, that did it, thanks